# Android app opening crash after adding AdMob in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, admob

I have a problem with using admob in my Unity game. After I added admob plugin v. 7.0.0 to the project and pointed project ID, the Android build crashes on start so that the project doesn't opens at all. Could you help me please to find a problem?

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: Use logcat to observe the logs when you run your program to look for clues.